# Large-scale gRNA design for a CRISPR screen

Tags: crispr

What are the best tools to design gRNAs in a high-throughput way for a CRISPR screen, e.g. targeting all protein-coding genes in a genome? I would like to take into account possible off-target effects, as well as to allow for flexibility in the PAM sequence, to have the possibility of using non-canonical PAMs.

I'm aware of [CRISPRseek](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/CRISPRseek.html), but I'm afraid it might be quite slow to run for a genome-scale search.

Comment: I don't have enough experience with CRISPR to give a useful answer. I have one observation though. You say that you are afraid that CRISPRseek *might* be quite slow for a genome-scale search. Have you actually tried? It sounds like this problem should parallelize well. Presumably, you could run one gene at a time, running as many in parallel as your resources allow?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [GenomeCRISPR](http://genomecrispr.dkfz.de/#!/), I've personally never used it, but it has a well-documented API and appears you could automate it to go through the whole genome.